# Programming outlook suite bar

Tags: outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I want to create a customized link in a suite bar of outlook web app. Is it possible to programmatically customize the suite bar of Outlook web app so I can add my own custom link?

Comment: could you share some additional context around what your action would do in Outlook web app? If you could also provide a screenshot of exactly where you are hoping to add the action this would also be helpful.

Comment: What I'm asking is if I want to add an additional button here and it would redirect to another page. Is it possible? https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFPg8.png

Comment: In your screenshot, I noticed only Outlook web app icons appear in the launcher. Is that mailbox part of an on-premises deployment of Exchange? I left an answer below, but it would only work for tenants in Office 365.

Comment: Are those tenants in Office 365 also covers exchange server users? Or those two are different from each other. Cause I found out that they are using Exchange server for their mail

Comment: Basically, I just want to add a custom link in outlook web app, like mail.mydomain.net/owa/newpage. And yes, that mailbox is part of an on premises deployment of Exchange. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to add links to the Office 365 app launcher.

Developers can build apps that use Azure AD for authentication and have them appear in the launcher. There are a few ways to do this, and they are described here: [Have your app appear in the Office 365 app launcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/connect-your-app-to-o365-app-launcher)

Secondly, admins can add custom tiles to the launcher by following the steps here: [Add custom tiles to the app launcher](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-custom-tiles-to-the-app-launcher-1136115a-75af-4497-b693-640c4ce70bc6)